# Conditional statement on MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, conditional-statements, exists

I want to do something like

```
IF (EXISTS (select * from Table1 where <Condition>))
{
    INSERT INTO Table2 ...
}
ELSE
{
    INSERT INTO Table3...
    <Do some more manipulations>
}
```

AFAIK I can only use the `IF` as part of a statement.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,

==Edit 1==
I would like to do this logic as part of a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Do you want this statements in procedure or trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE <CONDITION>) THEN 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2 ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table3...
    <DO SOME more manipulations>
END
END IF
```

Check [**IF Statement**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) in **MySQL**

Answer (score 0):

The only way is by calling a stored procedure.

Using stored procedure, you can define variables, check multiple conditions, execute multiple statements, etc.
But, just with `IFEXISTS` and `ELSE` at max you can execute 2 statements in straight.

***References***: [***MySQL: CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)